# Only prepend after removed from end using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, prepend

I made this script which is working quite well. It gets a feed with a varying number of elements. Then if, for example, there are 5 elements it removes 5 from the end and prepends 5 to the start.

Unfortunately there seems to be a problem where it is not always waiting for the elements to be fully removed from the end before prepending them. This causes the footer to be bumped up and down.

I wonder if anyone knows how to fix my problem. I tried adding a delay but that only partially helped.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.setInterval(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: location.protocol+'//'+location.hostname+'/index/feed',
            success: function(data) {

                var arr = data.split('@@@@@@@@@');

                $('#feed > .feed-item').slice(-1 * arr[0]).fadeOut(1000, function(){
                    $(this).remove();
                });

                $("#feed").delay(2000).prepend(arr[1]);

            }
        });

    },2000);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change the code a little bit in order to make it work locally, but I think this example can give you a good grasp.

I create a function: removeFeed(callback) that receives a function as a parameter, this function is invoked just after the remove statement.

inside de success in $.ajax you create a anonymous function as the parameter for removeFeed and inside you put the prepend function.

Hope it helps!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var root = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
    var counter = 1;

    function removeFeed(callback) {
        $('#feed > .feed-item').fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $(this).remove();
            callback();
        });
    }
    window.setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: root + '/posts/' + (counter + 1),
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(data) {

                removeFeed(function() {
                    $("#feed").prepend("<li class='feed-item'>" + data.title + "</li>");
                })

            }
        });

    }, 2000);
});
```

ps: it's fully functional, to see it working just copy and paste in a page.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('#feed > .feed-item').slice(-1 * arr[0]).fadeOut(1000, function(){
                    $(this).remove();
                });
```

Since you are using fadeout here , function inside your fadeout would be called in a callback.

So you prepend would get executed first and feed item would be removed.
Remove fadeOut and you can use css fadeout effects

Comment: Hmmm, so that is what is causing it. I wonder if anyone can come up with some jquery solution though.